# Python - Read excel range and transform moving multiple columns into single column

Tags: python, excel, transpose

I have daily sales data in excel that looks like image below. It has columns as below

Date,
Weekday,
NorthSales,
NorthProjection,
SouthSales,
SouthProjection,
EastSales,
EastProjection,
WestSales,
WestProjection

[image: Input data]

I tried the code below that lets me read the excel range but I am having a challenge transposing the columns

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(filename='data.xlsx', 
                   read_only=True)

ws = wb['Sheet2']

# Read the cell values into a list of lists
data_rows = []
for row in ws['A3':'D20']:
    data_cols = []
    for cell in row:
        data_cols.append(cell.value)
    data_rows.append(data_cols)

# Transform into dataframe
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data_rows)
```

I would like to transform the data so the structure looks like

Date,
Weekday,
Zone, Sales,
Projection

[image: Expected output]

Comment: Why not just use `pd.read_excel` to read the file? Then `melt` to reshape the data.

Comment: Thank you BigBen. It worked the way I wanted.

Comment: Feel free to post your solution as an answer, so that others know the question has been resolved.